# Deploy token for GitLab project via command line

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible for GitLab project to generate "Deploy Token" remotely, via command line?
I'd like to automate creation of my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not via the [GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/deploy_tokens.html) at the moment.

There is an [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/21811) which is looking to add a set of new API endpoints that will allow administrators to create, list and revoke GitLab Deploy Tokens.